# Sending extra data beside or inside a new smart contract

Tags: contract-deployment, security

I'm doing a research about Ethereum smart contracts security and I need to send some extra data (for example some json data) beside or inside a new smart contract when I'm deploying that contract on the network.
Is it possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Should smart contract's code have an access to the data?  Should the data be stored in the blockchain, or maybe it would be enough to store the data off-chain, and only store the hash of the data on-chain?

Comment: Only Ethereum client (like hyperledger besu that i'm using) needs to access and read the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to to this.  First, you may just embed the data into smart contract's code like this:

```solidity
contract Foo {
  string public constant bar = "Hello, World!";
}
```

Second, you may pass the data as a constructor parameter:

```solidity
contract Foo {
  constructor (string memory _bar) public {
  }
}
```

In this example, constructor doesn't do anything with the data.  However, off-chain applications will still be able to access the data.  To make such accsss more convenient, you may log the data in event:

```solidity
contract Foo {
  event Bar (string bar);

  constructor (string memory _bar) public {
    emit Bar (_bar);
  }
}
```

If you want the data to be accessible by other functions of this smart contract, you may save it into a storage variable:

```solidity
contract Foo {
  string private bar;

  constructor (string memory _bar) public {
    bar = _bar;
  }
}
```

If you need the data to be accessible by other smart contracts, make the storage variable public:

```solidity
contract Foo {
  string public bar;

  constructor (string memory _bar) public {
    bar = _bar;
  }
}
```

If you don't need the ability to read the data, but only to verify it, consider storing, only the hash of the data:

```solidity
contract Foo {
  bytes32 public barHash;

  constructor (string memory _bar) public {
    barHash = keccak256 (bytes (_bar));
  }
}
```

or even pass only the hash to save gas on deployment:

```solidity
contract Foo {
  bytes32 public barHash;

  constructor (bytes32 _barHash) public {
    barHash = _barHash;
  }
}
```

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put in the data field any arbitrary data, but the transaction has a size limit, is about **780kB** AFAIK.